# BSimagepicker into imageview

Tags: ios, swift, image

Is there a way to add multiple selected images (with BSimagePicker) into a Imageview?

BSimagePIckerCode

```
@IBAction func showImagePicker(sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()
    vc.maxNumberOfSelections = 10

    bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
        select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            print("Selected: \(asset)")
        }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            print("Deselected: \(asset)")
        }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Cancel: \(assets)")
        }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Finish: \(assets)")
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Imageview Code

```
func imagePickerController(picker: BSImagePickerViewController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    imageView.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hi did you post something? Because i cant see anything.

Comment: Were you able to populate the imageview?

Answer (score 3):

To convert the array of assets in to array of images add following code to the method of BSImagePicker.

First of all Create global array of assets. Here i have created

```
var SelectedAssets = [PHAsset]()
```

Then call the method of BSImagepicker add following code.

```
bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
                                    select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
                                        print("Selected: \(asset)")
        }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            print("Deselected: \(asset)")
        }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Cancel: \(assets)")
        }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            print("Finish: \(assets)")
            print(assets.count)
            for i in 0..<assets.count
            {
                self.SelectedAssets.append(assets[i])
                print(self.SelectedAssets)
            }
        }, completion: nil)
```

Create One Method That Converts Your array of assets into array of images. Here I have Created a method.

```
func getAllImages() -> Void {

    print("get all images method called here")
    if SelectedAssets.count != 0{
        for i in 0..<SelectedAssets.count{
            let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            var thumbnail = UIImage()
            option.synchronous = true
            manager.requestImageForAsset(SelectedAssets[i], targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .AspectFill, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
                thumbnail = result!
            })
            self.PhotoArray.append(thumbnail)
        }
    }
    ImagesCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

In Above method i m using Collection View to display all selected images.

Now perform selector method in view will appear that will perform the get all images method after delay. as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.performSelector(#selector(ViewController.getAllImages), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)
}
```

That's It You will get the selected images... Hope it will help you..

Comment: Thanks it really help me alot :)